# Tags < ? e ?> interpretadas como comentario html

Tags: php, html

Estou com problemas em uma aplicação onde algumas as tags `<? ?>` estão sendo confundidas com comentários html. Segue o trecho de codigo.

```
<h3><?= $cadastros->num_rows(); ?> registro(s)</h3>

<? foreach($cadastros -> result() as $cadastro): ?>
```

No codigo fonte, ele interpreta as setas como comentário html.

Comment: se não me falha a memoria.. nas novas versões do php teve uma modificações na simplificação.. se não me engano, agora deve ser utilizado <?=   ?> para simplificar, e ali  no inicio do seu foreach ali ..ta faltando o igual.. para ficar.. <?=

Comment: Já testei com o <?= E da erro no foreach.

Comment: amigo, posta todo o código do seu foreach para ver... geralmente eu faço um foreach abrindo e fechando { } ..  abraços

Comment: <? foreach($cadastros -> result() as $cadastro): ?><!--erro-->
      <tr>
       <td><?= $cadastro->id ?></td>
       <td><?= $cadastro->nome ?></td>
       <td><?= $cadastro->telefone ?></td>
       <td><?= $cadastro->email ?></td>
       <td><?= $cadastro->observacoes ?></td>
       <td><?= anchor("cadastro/edit/$cadastro->id", "Editar") ?>
         | <a href="#" class='confirma_exclusao' data-id="<?= $cadastro->id ?>" data-nome="<?= $cadastro->nome ?>" />Excluir</a></td>
      </tr>
      <? endforeach; ?>

Comment: testei em um servidor externo e funcionou corretamente

Comment: edita sua primeira postagem e coloca o codigo do foreach la.. assim é rum de ver.. Esse servidor que vc testou utiliza qual versão do php?

Answer (score 2):

Habilite a `short_open_tag` no php.ini

Busque por "short_open_tag", encontre a linha e altere o valor da configuração.

Answer (score 0):

Provável que a diretiva [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) esteja desativada.

1) Verifique se está ativada:

- Via linha de comando:

  php -i | grep short_open_tag
- Via arquivo `.php`:

  phpinfo();

2) Encontre os arquivos `.ini` para efetuar alteração:

```
php --ini
```

e retornará algo como:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.1/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d
```

3) Procure o no `.ini` que está sendo carregado em `Loaded Configuration File`, altere o valor da diretiva `short_open_tag`;

4) Reinicie o `Apache`